# Why does my firebase storage show nearly a gigabyte used, despite me not using the storage api at all?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

When I look at my project on the firebase admin console, I see 835MB of Storage used. This strikes me as very odd, since I'm not using the Storage feature of firebase - only the firestore database and auth apis.

I only have 11 documents in my firestore, none of which contain more than a couple paragraphs' worth of strings. It is not 1 GB of data by any metric I know of. I'm not even sure if firestore data shows up as part of the Storage usage.

Why am I using so much Storage?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you're having a problem with information in the Firebase console, you should reach out to Firebase support directly.  Stack Overflow is highly unlikely to be of help. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: If you're using Cloud Functions, this is most likely due to a contain image being left over in Cloud Storage after a build. See https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firestore-web#7

Comment: How do you guys respond so fast? Does stackoverflow send you a notification when a firebase question is posted? And yes, I did use a cloud function in the past although not anymore. I guess I have to figure out how to clean that up...hmm...I went and deleted all the old functions that I no longer use, now I guess I wait and see if that number updates.

Comment: If you go to the Cloud Storage panel in the Google Cloud console for the project, you can see all buckets associated with your project and find it there. The question I linked also explains how to remove these containers.